# dismiss ViewC controller that i present it by using root

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

how could i dismiss a view controller that i call it by using this method

```
func openUpgradeAccount(){

    let appdel = AppDelegate.sharedInstance()

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let earnFreeSpace = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("IAPUpgradeVC") as! IAPUpgradeVC

    let navigation:UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: earnFreeSpace)
    appdel.drawerController!.mainViewController = navigation
    appdel.drawerController!.setDrawerState(.Closed, animated: true)
}
```

in this controller i add UIBarButtonItem to cancel id viewdidload method

```
    let cancelBarBtn = UIBarButtonItem(title: NSLocalizedString("Cancel", tableName: appLocalizedTable, comment: ""), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: #selector(IAPUpgradeVC.didTapCancelButton(_:)))
    cancelBarBtn.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelBarBtn
```

the didTapCancelButton method that i use to dismiss the view was

```
    func didTapCancelButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) { () -> Void in

    }
```

but when i tap cancel button nothing happen , what i want how can i return back to the last ViewController , can  anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what is the drawerController? What's its superclass and what's its mainViewController supposed to be?

The method that you call when tapping the button is for dismissing a view controller presented modally. However before that, you do not present that view controller modally, setting is as drawerController's mainViewController instead:

```
appdel.drawerController!.mainViewController = navigation
```

One way to make it work is to change this line, so that instead of setting mainViewController you call presentViewController to present the new view controller modally.

If that is not how you want it to work (no presentation of view controllers), you'd have to elaborate on what you want both the new vc and the drawerController to do.

Comment: drawerController it a class the change the cell background color in my left menu when i tap it ,,

Comment: I was actually more curious about what are its superclasses?

Comment: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

Comment: So did the solution with `presentViewController` work for you?